# Why doesn't ClearAll["Global'*"] remove all variables?

Tags: variable-definitions

Consider the following code :

```
In[19]:= a = 2;

In[20]:= ClearAll["Global'*"];

In[21]:= a

Out[21]= 2
```

As you see, the variable a hasn't been resetted. Why ?
ClearAll["Global'*"] is supposed to clear all user defined symbol : [How do I clear all user defined symbols?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/850/how-do-i-clear-all-user-defined-symbols)

Comment: `$\neq$'${}{}{}$

Comment: not `ClearAll["Global'*"];` but `ClearAll["Global\`*"];`