# How to clear all variables?

Tags: core-language, clear

I have noticed that the old trick of using:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
```

does not appear to work anymore. It does not clear the values of any of my variables. I assume this has to do with some sort of change in Mathematica.

Does anyone have a replacement for this?

NOTE: I also tried using the following without success:

```
ClearAll @@ {$Context<>"*"}
```

Comment: What does `Context[variable]` return for one of the variables that isn't cleared?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I clear all user defined symbols?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/850/how-do-i-clear-all-user-defined-symbols)

Comment: `ClearAll["Global`*"]` should be working for you.  Seems to be a local issue instead of a universal one.

Comment: @Carl Woll - Context[variablename] just returns itself, i.e. the output is Context[variablename]

Answer (score 3):

I find quitting and restarting the kernel to be the best way.

Comment: E.g. using `Quit[]`  This has the added advantage of restoring any system definitions that you might have accidentally over-written.